# Changing menu links to any word?

Tags: html, hyperlink

How can I change my linked pages names, like home.html, about.html, contact.html ... to any word? Instead of www.mypage.com/about.html to show www.mypage.com/about/

Thanks

Comment: This question is rather incomplete.  What server are you using? Is it IIS, Apache, nginx?  The server used will greatly affect the answer to this question, but generally, it sounds like you need a redirect of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www.mypage.com/about.html` references a **file**. `www.mypage.com/about/` references a **folder**. When users visit `www.mypage.com/about/`, they are visiting the index of that page -- either `www.mypage.com/about/index.php` or `www.mypage.com/about/index.html`.

The most *simple* way to change the names in your urls would be to change `www.mypage.com/about.html` to `www.mypage.com/about/index.html`, and update your links.

However, if what you're asking is if it's possible to have a user who visits `www.mypage.com/about.html` automatically redirected to `www.mypage.com/about`, you can achieve automatic redirection through either creating a file in the first location with JavaScript / PHP code that automatically redirects, or use an `.htaccess` file:

Folder to file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/about/ about.html [R=301,L]
```

File to folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule about.html ^/about/ [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps!